# Mongoose and Express - FindbyIdandUpdate overwrites the value of the first array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating like a fast food online service for ordering food(I'm just practicing). The thing that bothers me now is I've successfully created an order when a customer picks a meal. After another meal is picked order is updated by order.id and another meal is added to the same order using $push. The problem that I have is when the order is created for the first time the first meal is overwritten by findbyIdAndUpdate when adding a second meal. After adding the third meal I get the data from the second meal and the third meal but the first one doesn't exist.I'm using MongoDB. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Sorry for the log and probably bad code in advance!

Order Schema is here:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    order: [{
        meal: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Menu'
        },
        quantity: String
    }],
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",

    }



});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Order", orderSchema);
```

Express route is here:

```
app.post("/menu/order", middlewareObject.isLoggedin, function (req, res) {
    let order = {
        user: req.user._id,
        meal: req.body.foodID,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,

    }
    if (app.locals.orderID !== undefined) {
        order._id = app.locals.orderID;
        console.log(order._id);
        Order.findByIdAndUpdate(order._id, {
            $push: {
                order: {
                    meal: order.meal,
                    quantity: order.quantity,

                }
            }
        }, function (err, updated) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("UPDATED!")
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        })
    } else {
        Order.create(order, function (err, newOrder) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("CREATED!")
                app.locals.orderID = newOrder._id;
                res.redirect("back");
            }
        })
    }

})
```

Create() data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6b78bd336a7324c63621c"), "user" : ObjectId("5eb6b788d336a7324c63621a"), "order" : [ ], "__v" : 0 }
```

FindByUpdateandID data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6ba776d8684455cb8ece5"), "user" : ObjectId("5eb6b788d336a7324c63621a"), "order" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6ba7d6d8684455cb8ece6"), "meal" : ObjectId("5eb6ba6a6d8684455cb8ecd7"), "quantity" : "5" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("5eb6ba7f6d8684455cb8ece7"), "meal" : ObjectId("5eb6ba6a6d8684455cb8ecd8"), "quantity" : "2" } ], "__v" : 0 }
```

Comment: After you create the first order (`Order.create(order, ...` what is the data you are seeing in the collection?

Comment: Hmm, it seems there is the problem,  there is actually no data in the order object. How to fix that ? I mean how to create it properly fo the first time.

Comment: You can post a copy of the sample document in your question (how does your document look like?).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you do you need the sample of the database? Ive edited the post and added those.

Comment: This data you are pushing into the array must also be inserted into the document, for the first insert: `order: { meal: order.meal, quantity: order.quantity, }`. It must be within the code: `} else { <log the order data here and see what is in it>, Order.create(...`

Comment: I get what i need  : {
  user: 5eb6d45f4d1b2430bcd1729e,
  meal: '5eb6d50ec37bd72a6cfb81e4',
  quantity: '2'
}, i just dont know how to implement it when using the .create

Comment: Thing that worked was: Order.create({
            order: {
                meal: order.meal,
                quantity: order.quantity,
            },
            user: req.user._id

        }, function (err, newOrder)... i didn't knew you can place object directly